# SSIS using ? as value to be passed in SQL Query using (IN) in OLEDB but has multiple values

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a ssis package.

It runs a for loop which loops parameter values which is passed into a sql command in the oledb source.

This loop is based on values that are in a sql table.

The table has 1 column called prefix with the following values:

```
Record 1: 234,235
Record 2: 434,435
```

This is the sql query in the oledb

```
SELECT *
FROM RandomTable
WHERE left(prefix,3) in (?)
```

When it runs it an read the first value in the parameter but it doesn't read the second one.
So when it runs it performs:

```
left(prefix,3) in ('234')
```

But I would like it to perform:

```
left(prefix,3) in ('234','235')
```

Is this possible using the question mark or I have to do this in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a parameter place holder `?` to express multiple values in SSIS.

Instead, what you need to do is classic string building to make your query work.

Create two Variables of type string: `QueryActual` and `QueryParameters`

QueryActual is going to be the following expression

```
"SELECT * FROM RandomTable WHERE left(prefix,3) IN (" + @[User::QueryActual] + ");"
```

Now you have restricted your problem domain to building the value for QueryParameters, which is appears you have with your sample data

```
'234','235'
```